# Is it possible to send the instance of class with member function between two process?

Tags: c++, ipc, interprocess

Consider I have this kind of class in process 1. And run process2 whose code is written in completely different file.

```cpp
class A{
public:
  int data;
  A()
  int f();
}
```

I want to make instance `a` of class `A` in process1, send it to process2, and run `a.f()` in process2. I studied about IPC mechanism including POSIX shared memory or message queue and read many examples, but the most of examples only expalin how to send single data like integer, or struct without member function.

1. Is it possible?
2. If it's possible, how can I do it using POSIX shared memory? Can you give me short example?

Comment: In C++, types (i.e. `class` definitions) don't necessarily exist at runtime: OOP is an abstraction used at design-time - plenty of languages _do_ reifiy their objects in their runtimes (like Java, C#/.NET, etc) but C++ doesn't.

Comment: There needs to be some communication or sharing mechanism, in which both processes cooperate.  For example, the two processes may *cooperatively* establish an area of shared memory, process 1 may construct an instance of `A` in that memory, communicate somehow with process 2 so process 2 knows their is an `A` in that memory, and then process 2 may call (in effect) `a.f()`.   The trick is defining communication and synchronisation between the processes (e.g. while process 1 is modifying `a.data`, process 2 must not attempt to do read it until process 1 is done - and vice versa).

Comment: There are many options.    The choice between options involves needs of *both* processes to access/modify data, while aware that the other process may also access/modify that data.   Your description is too simplistic to offer useful advice on what options might be appropriate.

Comment: I think I confuse you because of using the word 'share'. What I want to do is more likely to be 'send'. I don't want to allow both process modify or access data at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible to do it in shared memory.

Take for example the following class:

```cpp
struct A {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    A(int initial_value) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        internal_value = initial_value;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    void write(int value) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        internal_value = value;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    int read() const {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        return internal_value;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    void watch(int value) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        while (internal_value == value) usleep(1000);                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    std::atomic<int> internal_value;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
};
```

The class uses an atomic counter inside that will be shared between two processes, both reading and writing from it.

Let's first create some shared memory space for it.

```cpp
    int mapsize = getpagesize();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    int fid = ::open("/tmp/shared.dat", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    ftruncate(fid, mapsize);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    void* ptr = ::mmap(nullptr, mapsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fid, 0);
```

Notice I am not checking the return values for brevity but you should do in your code.

Now with this memory space allocated, let's initialize an object of class "A" inside that memory with placement new.

```cpp
    A* a = new (ptr) A(0);  // placement new
```

Then we fork another process to simulate the IPC mechanism working

```cpp
    pid_t pid = fork();
```

For the parent process code, we loop from 0 to 10 first waiting for it to be different from zero then 2, 4 etc. Then in the end we wait for the child to finish.

```
    if (pid != 0) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j += 2) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            printf("-->parent %d\n", j);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            a->watch(j);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            a->write(j + 2);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        printf("Finishing parent\n");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        int status;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        wait(&status);
```

For the child process, we write 1 and wait for 1, then write 3 and wait for 3 and so on like the parent but with odd numbers.

```cpp
    } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        for (int j = 1; j < 10; j += 2) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            printf("-->child %d\n", j);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            a->write(j);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            a->watch(j);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        printf("Finishing child\n");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    }
```

In the end of both we unmap the memory and close the file

```cpp
    ::munmap(ptr, mapsize);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    ::close(fid);
```

It prints:

```bash
-->parent 0
-->child 1
-->parent 2
-->child 3
-->parent 4
-->child 5
-->parent 6
-->child 7
-->parent 8
-->child 9
Finishing parent
Finishing child
```

Compiler Explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/5orPaEhPM

If you need two independent processes running side by side you just need to be careful with how you create them, synchronize them.

Start the same way opening a file and memory mapping it

```cpp
    int mapsize = getpagesize();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    const char* filename = "/tmp/shared.dat";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    int fid = ::open(filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    void* ptr = ::mmap(nullptr, mapsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fid, 0);
```

Notice that at this point if you write or read from the pointer `ptr` you will get a segfault.

Then you need to lock the file

```cpp
    while (flock(fid, LOCK_EX) != 0) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        usleep(10000);   // sleep a bit
    }
```

Then you need to check the file. If the size is zero, it is uninitialized. If the file is already initialized, you do not use placement new, you just cast the raw pointer.

```cpp
    A* a;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    if (getfilesize(fid) == 0) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        ftruncate(fid, mapsize);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        a = new (ptr) A(0);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(ptr);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    }
```

After that you read your value and increment it while the file is still locked.

```cpp
    int value = a->read();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    value += 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    a->write(value);
```

Then you can unlock the file

```cpp
    flock(fid, LOCK_UN);  // unlock
```

Then it's just the same drill of waiting, incrementing and looping, only a tad different.

```cpp
    // Change 5 times                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        printf("-->proc %d %d\n", getpid(), value);                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        a->watch(value);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        value += 2;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        a->write(value);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    }
```

In the end, just unmap and close as before

```cpp
    ::munmap(ptr, mapsize);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    ::close(fid);
```

The whole code is here: https://godbolt.org/z/zK3WKWqj4

Comment: Thanks, but I miss something to ask. Is it possible if two process is written in completely different file? Not parent and child process.

Comment: Yes, same solution. I only did `fork()` here to simplify the example.

Comment: I updated it to reflect your question - it works as separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

Do not to use IPC, but RPC  (Remote Procedure Calls) for that. E.g. gRPC : https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/introduction/. Sharing data "manually" with shared memory can be done but you end up having to write synchronization mechanism yourself (locks on data, signals that data has been written into shared memory etc.)